# Is there any built in LED connected with GPIO pin?

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, led

In Arduino a built in LED is attached with number 13 Digital pin.
Is there any LED like Arduino in Raspberry Pi,which I can use to test my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the Pi has no GPIO programmable built-in LED.

Edit: This is incorrect. As pointed out in an answer below, the on-board can be controlled using `echo none > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger` to enable,  `echo 1 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` to turn the LED on, and `echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` to turn the LED off.

The rest of my previous answer for controlling an external LED...

Instead, you'd have to make a simple circuit between two pins, e.g. pin 9 and 11 (https://pinout.xyz/), with an LED and resistor (around 100 ohms should be fine). You can then control the LED using the `gpio` command. `gpio mode 11 out` to enable output, `gpio write 11 1` to turn on the LED, and `gpio write 11 0` to turn off the LED.

More details are available at https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. otherwise I would go look for this an this would be total time waste.

Comment: -1. It has always been possible to flash one on-board LED. The methods are diffrerent from model to model, though.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible to control the built-in leds. Green LED is easier.

According to [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12530#p136266), though it is probably Pi 3 specific, since it didn't work for my Pi 4:

In the terminal:

```
sudo echo 1 > sudo /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
```

This turns the green led on.

```
sudo echo 0 > sudo /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
```

To turn off the activity indicator override: (put it back how it was)

```
echo mmc0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

Answer (score 9):

> though it is probably Pi 3 specific, since it didn't work for my Pi 4

It works on the 4 as well, you just need to set the right trigger. The instructions that you provided are not applicable to the 4 or just incorrect.

This will tell you what triggers you have available:

```bsh
cat /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

To enable manual control on a 4, do:

```bsh
echo gpio |sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

Then control with:

```bsh
# Any number > 0 will do
echo 255 |sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness

# Zero turns it off
echo 0 |sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
```